# Printing braces

Tags: java, optimization

Question goes like this :

```
input: 1
output:
{}

input: 2
output:
{}{}
{{}}

input: 3
output:
{}{}{}
{{}}{}
{}{{}}
```

This is my program :

```
public class PrintBraces {
    int n;
    char []braces;

    void readData()
    {
        java.util.Scanner scn=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the value of n : ");
        n=scn.nextInt();
    }

    void manipulate()
    {
        braces=new char[n*2];

        for(int i=0;i<2*n;i+=2)
        {
            braces[i]='{';
            braces[i+1]='}';
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int oddNo=2*i-1;
            if(oddNo>0)
            {
                char temp=braces[oddNo];
                braces[oddNo]=braces[oddNo+1];
                braces[oddNo+1]=temp;

                print();

                temp=braces[oddNo];
                braces[oddNo]=braces[oddNo+1];
                braces[oddNo+1]=temp;
            }
            else
            {
                print();
            }
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(braces[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

```
class PrintMain
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        PrintBraces pb=new PrintBraces();
        pb.readData();
        pb.manipulate();
    }
}
```

As expected, I get the correct answer.

I have solved it but I think it isn't efficient enough. Can anyone optimise it? And I would love to see any other alternative approaches for the same problem. May be a recursive one?
Also, I am open to any suggestions for improving my programming style. Any good practices that I may be violating in my code?

Comment: Why doesn’t the output for `3` contain `{{{}}}`? Are only two levels of nesting allowed?

Answer (score 6):

```
public class Solution{

    public static void par(int n, int open, int closed, String str) {

        if (closed == n) {
            System.out.println(str);
            return;
        }

        if (open < n) {
            par(n, open+1, closed, str + "{");
        }

        if (closed < open) {
            par(n, open, closed+1, str + "}");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        par(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), 0, 0, "");

    }
}
```

Output fot the testcase 3:

```
{{{}}}
{{}{}}
{{}}{}
{}{{}}
{}{}{}
```

If you need additional speed - you should use the buffered output. Something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution{

    static BufferedWriter out; 

    public static void par(int n, int open, int closed, String str)  throws IOException {

        if (closed == n) {
            out.write(str + "\n");
            return;
        }

        if (open < n) {
            par(n, open+1, closed, str + "{");
        }

        if (closed < open) {
            par(n, open, closed+1, str + "}");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 4096);
        par(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), 0, 0, "");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

For example the first version for 13 takes ~ **17** seconds:

```
timethis %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -server Solution 13 >13.txt
```

the buffered output version ~ **0.4** second!

PS. Interesting that jdk1.7.0_04 ~ **5** times faster than that c version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

unsigned long pairs_count;
unsigned long *brackets;
unsigned long found = 0;

void print_result()
{
    unsigned long i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < pairs_count; i++) {
    printf("(");

    for (j = 0; j < pairs_count; j++)
        if (brackets[j] == i)
        printf(")");
    }

    printf("n");
    found++;
}

void step(unsigned long start_val, unsigned long pos)
{
    unsigned long k, i;

    if (start_val > pos)
    k = start_val;
    else
    k = pos;

    for (i = k; i < pairs_count; i++) {
    brackets[pos] = i;

    if (pos == pairs_count - 1)
        print_result();
    else
        step(i, pos + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{

    scanf("%d", &pairs_count);

    brackets = new unsigned long[pairs_count];

    if (!brackets) {
    printf("Unsufficient memory.n");
    return (0);
    }

    step(0, 0);

    delete brackets;

    printf("Found: %d.n", found);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you guide me through the code? I personally find it difficult to grasp recursive algos and I need to get good at it. So can you suggest me a good source for mastering recursive algos?

Comment: Nice, very clean implementation (but an explanation would be in order). Now, how to rewrite it using dynamic programming?

Comment: +1 - String concatenation isn't the most efficient thing around.  Of course, passing `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` wouldn't help much, because you'd need to copy them at each level - This might warrant a custom `CharSequence` or something (as linked list?  Although `String` may have this behavior by default...).  Code is a lot cleaner than what I was initially coming up with, although a bit of an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The algorithm is very simple:
1. The first brace is {
2. The last brace is }
3. On the same level } goes right after {
4. The amount of { braces is equal to amount of the } braces.
5. Recursion does the rest job.

Answer (score 4):

The given problem can be attempted in a slightly different manner. You can see that the pairing corresponds to binary digits with { standing for 1s and } standing for 0s.

For e.g the pairing with the maximum value for say 4 {}'s is 11110000. So all we have to do is to generate every number from 1 to 11110000 and strike out all numbers that do not conform to our requirement - that is, at no point while counting the digits from left in a number, can the number of 1s be lesser than the number of 0s, and also that the total count of 1s and 0s must be equal.

A few optimizations can be done, For e.g, all odd numbers can be eliminated. And the total number of digits have to be even, etc.

If the number of braces are `n`, then the algorithm is of `O(2^n)` complexity. So it is not an efficient algorithm. I wonder what the complexity of your algorithm is, and how you can show that your algorithm is indeed correct.

For additional ideas ref: catalan numbers.

Comment: Excellent idea ... post some code. I am all for non-recursive solutions when they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my effort. It's a little like @cat_baxter's one. The point I am making here is that if you add loads of comments to your code, sometimes just the effort of doing so makes the code better.

I think this is optimal, i.e. it never starts growing a sequence towards an invalid position, but I don't fancy trying to prove that.

```
public class PrintBraces {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Do a number of them.
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Print Braces: " + i);
      printBraces(i);
    }
  }

  private static void printBraces(int n) {
    // There will always be n*2 characters in the brace array.
    char[] braces = new char[n * 2];
    // Start at position 0 with 0 opened.
    printBraces(braces, 0, 0);
  }

  private static void printBraces(char[] braces, int opened, int offset) {
    // How much space is left in the array?
    int space = braces.length - offset;
    // Are we at the end of the array?
    if (space > 0) {
      // We can open or close so try both.
      // We can only open if there is enough room to close all opened and at least one more.
      if (space > opened) {
        printBraces(braces, opened, offset, true);
      }
      // We can only close if we are opened more than once.
      if (opened > 0) {
        printBraces(braces, opened, offset, false);
      }
    } else {
      // Array is full! Is it legal?
      if (opened == 0) {
        System.out.println(braces);
      } else {
        // Here just for my sanity. Code never gets here - proving we are correct.
        System.out.println("?-" + braces);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void printBraces(char[] braces, int opened, int offset, boolean open) {
    // Add that kind of brace and recurse.
    braces[offset] = open ? '{' : '}';
    printBraces(braces, opened + (open ? 1 : -1), offset + 1);
  }
}
```